# How can you gather() multiple columns at the same time in dplyr (R)?

Tags: r, select, dplyr, tidyr

I am trying to gather untidy data from wide to long format.
I have 748 variables, that need to be condensed to approximately 30.

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55939255/tidying-in-r-how-to-collapse-my-binary-columns-into-characters-based-on-vector), I asked: how to tidy my wide data? The answer: use gather().

However, I am still struggling to gather multiple columns and was hoping you could pinpoint where I'm going wrong.

Reproducible example:

```
tb1 <- tribble(~x1,~x2,~x3,~y1,~y2,~y3,
       1,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,
       NA,1,NA,NA,NA,1,
       NA,NA,1,NA,NA,1)

# A tibble: 3 x 6
#     x1    x2    x3 y1       y2    y3
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1    NA    NA NA        1    NA
#2    NA     1    NA NA       NA     1
#3    NA    NA     1 NA       NA     1
```

with x1-y3 having the following characteristics:

```
1 x1    Green 
2 x2    Yellow
3 x3    Orange
4 y1    Yes   
5 y2    No    
6 y3    Maybe
```

I tried this:

```
tb1 %>%
  rename("Green" =x1,
         "Yellow"=x2,
         "Orange"=x3,
         "Yes"=y1,
         "No"=y2,
         "Maybe"=y3) %>%
  gather(X,val,-Green,-Yellow,-Orange) %>%
  gather(Y,val,-X) %>%
  select(-val)
```

I did get an output that I wanted for these variables, but I can't imagine how to do this for 700+ variables?! Is there a more effective way?

```
tb1 %>%
  rename("Green" =x1,
         "Yellow"=x2,
         "Orange"=x3,
         "Yes"=y1,
         "No"=y2,
         "Maybe"=y3) %>%
  gather(X,val,-Green,-Yellow,-Orange) %>%
  filter(!is.na(val)) %>%
  select(-val) %>%
  gather(Y,val,-X) %>%
  filter(!is.na(val)) %>%
  select(-val)

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  X     Y     
  <chr> <chr> 
1 No    Green 
2 Maybe Yellow
3 Maybe Orange
```

I think I might be just not acquainted enough with gather() so this is probably a stupid question - would appreciate the help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m assuming the issue here is with manually specify all the different variable names. Luckily, `tidyverse` has the `?select_helpers` which make it easier to select columns based on different rules.

Instead of renaming the variables at the beginning, we can rename them at the end. This lets us use `starts_with` to get all columns starting with `x` or `y` and gather them together in one step. Then we can use `ends_with` to select the value columns from those gather steps and filter and drop them.

Finally, we replace all values of `x1`, `y1` etc. with their true values in one step using `mutate_all` and a lookup table

```
# Make lookup table to match X and Y variables with Values
  # the initial values should be the `names` (first) and the values to change them to
  # should be the `values` (after the =)
lookup <- c('x1' = 'Green',
            'x2' = 'Yellow',
            'x3' = 'Orange',
            'y1' = 'Yes',
            'y2' = 'No',
            'y3' = 'Maybe')

tb1 %>%
    gather(X, Xval, starts_with('x')) %>%    # Gather all variables that start with ‘x'
    gather(Y, Yval, starts_with('y')) %>%    # Gather all variables that start with ‘y'
    filter_at(vars(ends_with('val')),        # Looking in columns ending with ‘val'
              all_vars(!is.na(.))) %>% %>%    # Drop rows if ANY of these cols are NA
    select(-ends_with('val')) %>%            # Drop columns ending in ‘val'
    mutate_all(~lookup[.])                   # Replace value from lookup table in all cols

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  X      Y 
  <chr>  <chr>
1 Green  No   
2 Yellow Maybe
3 Orange Maybe
```

One tricky thing with select_helpers is knowing when you an use them alone and when you need to “register” them with `vars`. In `gather` and `select`, you can use them as is. In `mutate`, `filter`, `summarize`, etc. you need to surround them with `vars`

Comment: Thank you for your help, this saves time. I figured out my gathering is still a little messy - apologies for the bad question, it is difficult to ask a question sometimes, especially when you don't know what is going wrong! Thanks a lot for your help : )